# Why won't Navbar align to the right side in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I want to get **ONLY** the "Account" navbar positioned on the far
right-hand side but `ms-auto` does not seem to work as I want it to:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Music Store!</title>
  </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-xl">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Website</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                  <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="about.php">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="contact.php">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    
                    <?php
                    session_start();
                    if(isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']))
                        {
                        ?>
                          <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="viewStock.php">Shop</a>
                          </li>    

                          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Account</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="viewOrder.php">Order History</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="viewListing.php">My Listings</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                        <?php
                        }
                        else{
                        ?>
                          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
           

                 <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Account</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="login.php">Login</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="createUser.php">Register</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>    
                    </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </nav>
        </div> <!-- End of container -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your css

```
.navbar-collapse{
  justify-content: end;
}
```

and remove the `me-auto` class from `<ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">`

and that should do the trick

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8zn9jkfs/

Comment: Thanks, but I am wanting Home, About, Contact all on the left and Account on the far right.